# DELETE records in one table that are the same records in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that matches certain columns and transfers them into a "Matched" table as reports come in from vendors.

The reports come in and data gets put in a "Incoming" table.  After this. I Join on certain columns and the records in which a certain column IS NOT NULL (the columns matched) and put these into the "Matched" table.

My question is this:

How do I delete the records that matched from the table in which I joined on?

The following is my join statement to the records that I want to delete from "Incoming" table:

```
SELECT * FROM Incoming I
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mathced M
ON I.Name = M.Name AND I.Type = M.Type AND I.Op = M.Op AND I.DSource = M.DSource AND IDate = M.Date
WHERE M.MatchedID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM Incoming I
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mathced M
  ON I.Name = M.Name
    AND I.Type = M.Type
    AND I.Op = M.Op
    AND I.DSource = M.DSource
    AND I.Date = M.Date
WHERE M.MatchedID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you...It was that simple.  I thought that might be the script but I didn't want to DELETE something I shouldn't have.  DELETE keyword always scares me.

Comment: I think I spoke to soon.  I am getting red squigglies under `OUTER` and under alias `M`

Comment: Don't afraid, just run the query.

Comment: look at my previous comment

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM Incoming I
LEFT OUTER JOIN Mathced M
ON I.Name = M.Name AND I.Type = M.Type AND I.Op = M.Op 
                   AND I.DSource = M.Source AND IDate = M.Date
WHERE M.MatchedID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the correct answer:

`DELETE I
FROM
    Incoming I
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Matched M 
    ON
        I.Name = M.Name
        AND I.Type = M.Type
        AND I.Op = M.Op
        AND I.DSource = M.DSource
        AND I.Date = M.Date
WHERE M.MatchedID IS NOT NULL`

......because you first have to tell the DBMS which table you are deleting from and then state the JOIN using the alias

Comment: All the other answers give you squigglies.